# Trying to solve for n for this complex equation ∥Sn−α∥<ϵ where Sn=(2n+i^n)/n

Tags: complex-analysis

$$S_n=\frac{2n+i^n}{n}$$
$$ \alpha= \lim_{n\to \infty }S_n = 2 $$

$$\Vert S_n-\alpha \Vert \lt \epsilon $$
I substitute into the equation $$\Vert S_n-\alpha \Vert \lt \epsilon $$
To get $$\Vert \frac{2n+i^n}{n}-2 \Vert \lt \epsilon $$
I simplified to get $$\Vert \frac{i^n}{n} \Vert \lt \epsilon $$
Then $$\Vert \sqrt[n]\frac{i^n}{n} \Vert \lt \sqrt[n]\epsilon $$
 $$\Vert \frac{i}{\sqrt[n]n} \Vert \lt \sqrt[n]\epsilon $$
 $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]n} \lt \sqrt[n]\epsilon $$
Rearranged the equation
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]\epsilon} \lt {\sqrt[n]n} $$
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]\epsilon})^n \lt ({\sqrt[n]n})^n $$
$$\frac{1^n}{\epsilon} \lt {n} $$
Finally $$\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lt \frac{n}{1^n} $$
So this is the answer i got. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am just trying to solve for n

Comment: $n$ is just any number... I don't understand what you are asking for. If your are searching for abound depending on $\epsilon$, you already got $1/\epsilon<n(\epsilon)$...